Remembering a movie where humans return to Earth in the Distant future
Trying to track down a movie I watched years ago.  Early 2000s maybe.  Might have been a direct to TV movie, but can’t really recall anymore.  Premise is a colony/exploration ship travelled away from Earth at relativistic speeds.  Ship arrives to a planet that turns out to be Earth 100,000 years (give or take) in the future.
The colony ship arrived at the destination, found nothing to colonize and returned home without waking the crew.  Meanwhile, aliens had come, destroyed the moon (turning it into a ring) converting the entire Earth into a jungle/swamp-like planet, where surviving humans had developed camouflaged skin.
Kind of a bizarre mashup of Planet of the Apes, Time Machine, and After Earth…

This is the 'mockbuster' AE: Apocalypse Earth.

AE: Apocalypse Earth begins with a segment of the human race escaping the planet after losing a war against alien invaders, in search of a new home in a ragtag fleet of ark ships. With the crews in suspended animation, the ships go mysteriously off course and land on a hostile alien world where the survivors must struggle to fight against an invisible alien menace. I say this is a mockbuster of After Earth, and clearly it is with its forest locale and opening scene of our hero awakening with a breathing apparatus on a crashing space ship, but thankfully the film is smart enough to steal from some much better movies as well to concoct its weird Frankenstein monster of a plot, so much so that it might ironically qualify as a mockbuster of Oblivion in its own right just by being so derivative without that fact deterring from the entertainment value.





For the record, this film is terrible. If you feel the urge to watch it, I'd recommend instead spending an hour and twenty-seven minutes tidying your bathroom cabinets and giving your toilet a really thorough clean.

That was it, thanks.  Many terrible movies are still great escapes.  But yes.  It is objectively terrible.
